# Android Studio: Where do my images need to be saved for this program to be able to show them in the RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

I am not sure where the images need to be saved for them to appear in the RecyclerView. Should they be in the drawable folder in resources? If so, isn't the code to input the image files missing?

I believe they should be saved on the device emulator, but I do not know where to save the image files. Please give me a directory if so.

Thank you!

Below are 4 Java classes, MainActivity.java, Item.java, MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java, and DisplayImage.java

Main Activity

```
package com.example.gridlayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String PIC_PATH =
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    private ArrayList<Item> images = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private RecyclerView gallery;
    int columns = 3;
    int PERMISSION_CODE = 1;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gallery = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        gallery.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, columns));
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Request permission if permission is not granted
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    PERMISSION_CODE);
        } else {
            updatePictures();
            MyRecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(R.layout.layout_row, images);

            gallery.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                updatePictures();
                MyRecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new
                        MyRecyclerViewAdapter(R.layout.layout_row, images);
                gallery.setAdapter(myAdapter);
            }
        }
    }
    public void updatePictures() {
        try {
            File f = new File(PIC_PATH);
            File[] files = f.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                if (files[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")) {
                    images.add(new Item(files[i].getAbsolutePath()));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

}
```

Start of Item

```
package com.example.gridlayout;

public class Item {
    private String imagePath;

    public Item(String imagePath) {
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }

    public String getImagePath() {
        return imagePath;
    }
}
```

MyRecyclerViewAdapter

```
package com.example.gridlayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private int listItemLayout;
    private ArrayList<Item> itemList;
    private String [] imagePaths;

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (itemList == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return itemList.size();
    }

    // Constructor of the class
    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(int layoutId, ArrayList<Item> itemList) {
        listItemLayout = layoutId;
        this.itemList = itemList;
        imagePaths = new String[itemList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < imagePaths.length; i++)
            imagePaths[i] = itemList.get(i).getImagePath();
    }

    // specify the row layout file and click for each row
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(listItemLayout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder myViewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }


    // load data in each row element
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(itemList.get(listPosition).getImagePath());
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(bm);
        holder.image.setTag(itemList.get(listPosition).getImagePath());
    }

    // inner class to initialize the views of rows
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener {

        public ImageView image;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent in = new Intent(view.getContext(), DisplayImage.class);
            in.putExtra("selectedIndex", getLayoutPosition());
            in.putExtra("imagePathArray", imagePaths);
            view.getContext().startActivity(in);
        }
    }
}
```

Display Image

```
package com.example.gridlayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class DisplayImage extends AppCompatActivity {

    private double x1=0, x2=0;
    private int selectedIndex = -1;
    String[] imagePathArray = null;

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_image);
        ImageView fullPicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullPicture);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            selectedIndex = extras.getInt("selectedIndex");
            imagePathArray = extras.getStringArray("imagePathArray");
        }

        if (imagePathArray != null && selectedIndex >= 0
                && selectedIndex < imagePathArray.length) {

            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePathArray[selectedIndex]);
            fullPicture.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }

        fullPicture.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                double distanceThreshold = 100;

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    x1 = event.getX();
                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    x2 = event.getX();
                    if ((x1 - x2) > distanceThreshold) {    // if right to left sweep event
                        selectedIndex++;
                        if (selectedIndex > imagePathArray.length - 1)
                            selectedIndex = imagePathArray.length - 1;
                    }
                    if ((x2 - x1) > distanceThreshold) {    //left to right sweep event
                        selectedIndex--;
                        if (selectedIndex < 0) selectedIndex = 0;
                    }
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePathArray[selectedIndex]);
                    fullPicture.setImageBitmap(bm);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Images can be stored in a variety of places depending on how you code things.  In you're adapter you're assuming that you get paths.  That would work if you save them to the filesystem.  That will not work with image resources, as resources are internal to your app, not part of the filesystem.

Your code is trying to list all the files in the directory `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`  Which will only work with images stored in the global pictures directory, not images embedded in your app (and isn't the best way to do that either).